# Installing .NET SDK on Ubuntu produces no executable dotnet file

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, .net-core, apt

Installing .NET SDK on Ubuntu 20.04 with the commands listed in the [Install .NET on Ubuntu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu#2004-) docs:

```
wget https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb -O packages-microsoft-prod.deb
sudo dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb
rm packages-microsoft-prod.deb

sudo apt-get update; \
  sudo apt-get install -y apt-transport-https && \
  sudo apt-get update && \
  sudo apt-get install -y dotnet-sdk-6.0
```

produces no `dotnet` executable.

```
Command 'dotnet' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo snap install dotnet-sdk
```

Listing files from the package:

```
dpkg -L dotnet-sdk-6.0 | grep -P "dotnet$"
```

gives

```
/usr/share/dotnet
```

The `/usr/share/dotnet` directory contains no executable. I compared this result with my other Ubuntu installation where I installed dotnet ages ago, and there it is installed in `/usr/share/dotnet` *but there exists a* `/usr/share/dotnet/dotnet` executable.

What am I doing wrong? How to install `dotnet` on Ubuntu with APT?

**Using snap is not an option.**

Comment: I assume this question belongs on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/tour) in the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: @V0ldek have you found a solution to that? Same problem here.

Comment: @andresantacruz I resolved it as described here: https://github.com/dotnet/installer/issues/12939 Basically reinstall of dotnet-host and then install the SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo apt reinstall dotnet-host` and then `sudo apt install dotnet-sdk-6.0` fixed the issue.

See: https://github.com/dotnet/installer/issues/12939

Comment: Does not work on Ubuntu 23.04

Answer (score 0):

`dpkg -S /usr/bin/dotnet` says that it was created by `dotnet-host`.
So maybe that package is missing in `dotnet-sdk-6.0` and must be installed separately. I imagine they will fix it in some future version.

tl;dr `$ sudo apt install dotnet-host`